# Why docker login command saves unencrypted password on my computer?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I've used `docker login` command and passed my credentials and I got warning `WARNING: login credentials saved in /Users/{my_username}/.docker/config.json`. I've checked that file and indeed my password is there unencrypted (base64 encoded only).

Why docker saved my password unencrypted? Shouldn't it save it in my key-chain (I am on Mac OS) or instead of saving password just generate some access token or something like that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is now solved, and as you suggest, you can save to the keychain (or use other "helpers"). Full details are in the Docker docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

For anyone interested in the history and why this wasn't a trivial fix:
https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/10318

Comment: Is it possible to run commands without previous `docker login`? For example by passing username/password along with specific command?

Comment: No, that's covered in that issue too.

Comment: I think a stop gap between this issue and a solution is to use environment variables to store creds the same way you might do that for a web host with private API keys.

Comment: haha, is it fixed yet?

Comment: @TsgabiXD yes, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Credential Store for this purpose. Here is the offical doc from Docker:

[Credential Store](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store)

Comment: without examples the documentation is not informative

Comment: I gave the keyword of official docker solution and its document page. Because the question is about a general consept not about a particular implementation problem. Also the answer from Adrian was not a proper solution, it was just a trick as i remember, he obviously had changed his answer according to my keyword after my answer. We can thank him. No body has to explain credential store in here, if you have a problem while implementation you can ask here about that particular case. And if an official document can not help you no body can help you Mr. Kalashnikov..

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was located at `/root/.docker/config.json`. I had to `sudo -s` in order to navigate there, at least, so that I could delete it...

Solutions:

- `docker login --password-stdin`
- Alternatively, just don't use `docker login`; you may not need it! Try running your `docker pull` command with `sudo` instead.