# How can I prevent docker from attempting to save my credentials at all?

Tags: docker

`docker login`, by default, stores my credentials.

There is a property in `%HOMEPATH%/.docker/config.json`, named "credsStore", which allows you to choose which credential manager to use.
For instance, `"credsStore": "wincred"` will use the Windows Credential Manager.

Removing `credsStore` from the config file entirely does not prevent docker from attempting to store credentials, as expected; instead, it stores my sensitive secrets in plaintext.

I want it to prompt me for my username/password every single time.
**Every single time.**

How can I prevent docker from attempting to save my credentials at all?

Comment: You can use keychain or `pass` password manager as an alternative https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers

Comment: True.  I don't want to use them, or any other password manager.

Comment: You can use `docker logout` as well.

Comment: My answer, and yes it ***is*** an option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77115748/1599699

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an option with the docker CLI.

The CLI itself is a frontend to the docker engine's API, so you could write your own client that does this. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader if you really desire this feature.

You can also perform these actions from inside of a temporary container that mounts the socket so that all login credentials are destroyed when the container exits, e.g.

```
docker run -it --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock docker /bin/sh -c "docker login && docker push ..."
```

Or you can just script a login/logout command to wrap your `docker push` but you'll need to avoid race conditions. e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh
docker login
docker push "$@"
docker logout
```

Call that script `docker-push` and run that instead of `docker push`.

Comment: (Responding to a deleted comment.) The logout should clear credentials from the `~/.docker/config.json`. If your desktop environment stores credentials in a credential manager, there may be added steps to clear that entry. If you aren't already, I recommend using Docker Hub's 2fa and a token instead of your password for the `docker login`. You can have a different token for each location, and it only gives access to push/pull, not to the web site.

Comment: Wrong, it is an option: "To run the docker login command non-interactively, you can set the `--password-stdin` flag to provide a password through `STDIN`. Using `STDIN` prevents the password from ending up in the shell's history, or log-files." (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#password-stdin)

Comment: @Andrew perhaps you misread the question. The OP does not want to run a login which would save credentials to the disk. They want to pass credentials to the docker pull/push/run commands.

Comment: No, actually, you have misunderstood his question. The crucial words in both the title and his last sentence: "at all", and the fact that he started off his question with mention of `docker login` storing credentials. So his question is about that, which he continues to talk about. That's a reasonable misunderstanding though, as he then ambiguously says, "Every single time." And of course I misunderstood your answer's meaning. I think it best to edit and clarify what "This" means in your first sentence; then we're all good.

Comment: @Andrew yes the question is about storing credentials, but in the `~/.docker/config.json` file or a credential helper, not the shell history. That will happen when you run a docker login, even with the `--password-stdin` flag.