# Unecrypted Docker password

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I recently built a docker image and upon completion docker throws a message that states:

WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /root/.docker/config.json.

I tried to navigate to the folder to see whether this was true but the file path doesn't exist.What could be the issue here? Is my password safe?

Comment: The config.json is on the host, not in the container. Does this answer your question? [Why docker login command saves unencrypted password on my computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31961934/why-docker-login-command-saves-unencrypted-password-on-my-computer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it's ok if you are working on your machine and not in a prod environment.

When you log in into a registry `docker login [OPTIONS] [SERVER]`( e.g [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/)), the command stores credentials in `$HOME/.docker/config.json` (Linux) or `%USERPROFILE%/.docker/config.json` (windows).

Docker uses "base64" encoding to generate the auth by using a combination of the user's username and password

Just logout and login from your registry and check again the content of the config:

```sh
docker logout
docker login -u <username> -p <password>
```

Verify: `cat $HOME/.docker/config.json`